# Xamarin Forms: UWP app clicking is not working as expected

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, click

I have a weird issue with my UWP version of the xamarin forms project. The clicking is not working as expected. Sometimes no response when clicking items (button, image), and sometimes top items are opening when clicking an item.

Please watch this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EvgxgZTkitserE77SCNY4igWd0R_VnQs/view?usp=sharing) for getting a clear idea. In this video, I am clicking the next button(Quiz page) several times, but no response. On the game page, the top item pages are opening when clicking an item. In android and ios, everything is working fine.

**Version Details:**

```
Xamarin Forms: 4.7.0.968
UWP target version: Windows 10, version 1903(10.0;Build 18362)
UWP Min version: Windows 10, Fall Creators Update(10.0; Build 16299)
```

Please help me to find the issue behind this. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

**Button Code**

```
<Button 
    Text="NEXT"
    TextColor="White"
    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
    BackgroundColor="#f5c74c" 
    Clicked="NextButtonClicked"
    WidthRequest="150"
    HeightRequest="40"
    FontSize="18"
    BorderRadius="20"/>
    
public void NextButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //action
}
```

Comment: It looks the button has not been specific size, could you mind share the button's xaml code for us?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Added the button code to question, could you please check

Comment: during the your video, it looks your button contains image, why it does not contain image code above?

Comment: Here is the complete xaml file link of quiz page, Line no: 883 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sIinlpArQu9lyZfMXk7A8y0gEnfRFVxL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you try to remove custom font and test again?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Solved this issue by updating the XF version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by updating the xamarin forms version to 4.8.0.1269.